# GCM Server handling NotRegistered Error Response

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I've learned based on the [GCM documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html) that if sending a message fails due to a device no longer being registered because the application was uninstalled on the device, or for other reasons, it will return an error value of "NotRegistered".

My question is, will the response also contain any data that identifies the device such as the, now invalid, registration ID?  I realize that I need to remove that device from the database so that it cannot be sent further messages, but I'm not sure how to go about identifying the device in the database on my server's end.  Any advice about this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to locate the registration ID to be removed based on the request that you sent to GCM.

If you are sending a URL encoded request, containing a single Registration ID, and get that error, you know you have to delete that Registration ID.

If you are sending a JSON request with multiple registration ID, the response contains either a message ID or an error message for each Registration ID you sent. If, for example, the 5th element in the response contains a `NotRegistered` error, the Registration ID matching this error is the 5th Registration ID in your JSON request.

Comment: This perfectly answers my question.  I wasn't sure if the results were returned in the same sequence as the registration IDs that were sent.  Thanks very much.